# How to disable BD PROCHOT

Tags: cpu

I use ThrottleStop to disable BD PROCHOT to stop the throttling of the CPU when on Windows. Since ThrottleStop is not available on Ubuntu, I tried searching for a solution. I was not able to make things work. There is one question about how to do it and it has been answered by saying that you have to create a C program to do that. I am unable to do that. Can someone suggest another way?


EDIT: I used Terminal to find a way to make it happen. Can someone tell me how to write a bash file for this so I can run it at every startup. I tried, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
sudo cpufreq-set -c 0 -g performance
sudo cpufreq-set -c 1 -g performance
sudo cpufreq-set -c 2 -g performance
sudo cpufreq-set -c 3 -g performance
sudo modprobe msr
TEST = `$(sudo rdmsr 0x1FC)`
sudo wrmsr 0x1FC $(TEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

I create the following file called `prochot.sh` and put it under `/usr/local/bin/`.

```
#!/bin/bash

modprobe msr

lcase="$(rdmsr 0x1FC)"  # the default output is in base 16 without 0x and character is in lower case
declare -i ID
ID=`echo "ibase=16; ${lcase^^}" | bc`  # switch to upper case and then convert to base 10.
#echo $ID
if [[ $((ID%2)) == 0 ]]; then
    echo "turn on PROCHOT"
    ID=ID+1
else
    echo "turn off PROCHOT"
    ID=ID-1
fi

wrmsr 0x1FC $ID
```

Grant it the execute permission with

```
sudo chmod +x prochot.sh
```

Then, I can turn off or on BD PROCHOT with

```
sudo prochot.sh
```