Keep getting Performance mode temporarily disabled due to high operation temperature alert in power settings
I am getting this issue in power settings after clean install Ubuntu 24.04.

But I checked the temperature of sensors, everything looks fine.


I had a similar issue a while ago, it turned out to be the CPU PROCHOT flag. Still not sure what caused it, but in the end I had to use a script to disable it (I know the risks but I was sure my temps were all fine...). Check out my question and the details/answers in case it's the same or at least look at the suggested turbostat command to check if you have any active or logged ...LIMIT_REASONS flags: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446577/
