Laptop is really slow when playing games or using programs like blender
Month ago i had auto windows update which turned my laptop really slow.
Couldn't restore to previous version and decided to  changed SO to Ubuntu. Now it's a little bit better but still i am getting 30 fps in Wukong benchmark. I have AMD ryzen 5 5600X and RTX 3070. Made some benchmarks and gpu works as intended but cpu is doing maybe 10-15% of it's potential. The best part is normally it works with 2-3.5 Ghz and when i turn on benchmark, frequency drops to 0.53 Ghz. How can i restore the performance of my laptop
EDIT: It's pretty new install, i purged Windows and installed Ubuntu + few programs like Steam and Blender and Omakub.
I use 550.120 nvidia driver. I made some benchmarks. Don't have any before installing Linux, but now in Wukong i got 30-35fps, in GeekBench you can see for yourself, and on superposition gpu was doing great. Also i checked the other Post where the main problem is flag PROCHOT but i don't have anything like this.
Here is my result of sudo turbostat --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 5 :
`
turbostat version 2023.11.07 - Len Brown <lenb@kernel.org>
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-48-generic root=UUID=afae604a-0e6a-44e9-a5dd-67540b46cb6d ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
CPUID(0): AuthenticAMD 0x10 CPUID levels
CPUID(1): family:model:stepping 0x19:21:2 (25:33:2) microcode 0x0
CPUID(0x80000000): max_extended_levels: 0x80000023
CPUID(1): SSE3 MONITOR - - - TSC MSR - HT -
CPUID(6): APERF, No-TURBO, No-DTS, No-PTM, No-HWP, No-HWPnotify, No-HWPwindow, No-HWPepp, No-HWPpkg, No-EPB
CPUID(7): No-SGX No-Hybrid
cpu0: cpufreq driver: acpi-cpufreq
cpu0: cpufreq governor: performance
cpufreq boost: 1
/dev/cpu_dma_latency: 2000000000 usec (default)
current_driver: acpi_idle
current_governor: menu
current_governor_ro: menu
cpu0: POLL: CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
cpu0: C1: ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x0
cpu0: C2: ACPI IOPORT 0x414
RAPL: 234 sec. Joule Counter Range, at 280 Watts
cpu0: MSR_RAPL_PWR_UNIT: 0x000a1003 (0.125000 Watts, 0.000015 Joules, 0.000977 sec.)
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ CorWatt PkgWatt
2.84    3929    13170   2.92    22.12
3.70    3659    38787   5.39    25.28
6.69    3944    26874   6.03    24.70
4.95    3970    26327   5.16    24.25
3.52    3971    22431   4.22    23.26
2.31    3955    10320   2.65    21.77
2.38    3828    14538   2.90    22.11
3.32    3836    19691   3.97    23.02
2.42    3997    13932   3.07    21.74
2.83    3975    13056   3.17    22.25
2.48    3982    10493   2.71    21.53
2.30    3807    10573   2.19    20.82
2.87    4038    21572   3.71    22.68
^C4.57  3826    17505   4.62    23.72

EDIT:
Opened laptop and applied new paste. of course i cleaned it and applied new thermal paste, but wukong benchmark shows no difference in performance. Also, in my settings -> Power, there is no option to change governor, there are only options to show percentage of battery, power saving things etc.
EDIT: Also i run dmesg | grep -i error and output is pretty interesting:
[    0.694287] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\MWTT], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20230628/dswload2-326)
[    0.694324] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
[    4.072893] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[   34.487321] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.487513] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.487855] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.487975] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.617138] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.617281] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.617367] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.617448] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.738149] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.738298] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.738391] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership
[   34.738475] [drm:nv_drm_master_set [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000700] Failed to grab modeset ownership

I tried uninstalling gpu driver, changed setting in grub:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amd_pstate=active clocksource=tsc intel_idle.max_cstate=1 processor.max_cstate=1 idle=nomwait acpi=force nvidia-drm.modeset=1"

and again, i can see small change in performance, but still it's far from good. Also i can't really do any changes in Bios so for example i can only turn on or off the acpi in grub

It sounds like thermal throttling on the processor, where the max CPU frequency gets scaled back to protect the processor from overheating. I only know how to investigate this with Intel processors. Is thermald running?

I do not really use any programs for optimization, it's brand new install besides steam and omakub

I'm not allowed to comment yet so I have to ask further questions as if it were an answer. I just wanted to know which GPU driver you're using and if you have tried any other benchmarks. Doug Smythies also commented earlier that it might be thermal throttling. So with that I also wanted to ask how old the laptop is and if you've changed the thermal paste on it yet

I use 550.120 nvidia driver. Apart from wukong benchmark i used GeekBench. Also i tested gpu with superposition. While was turned on all effects, fps were around 60 so it's okay

Okay, so it looks to me that the geek bench scores are showing very inconsistent scores for this exact model of laptop running the exact same version of Ubuntu. I'm still thinking this is thermal related. I want to mention as well, I haven't looked up pictures of your laptop but most laptops use the same heat sync for both the CPU & GPU, meaning that when ever you're gaming the CPU is getting cooked even when it's not doing much. You might have to consider lowering graphics quality and if you can try to tune fan curves. (I need to look up the name of an app for this, I used to use)

I forgot to add, laptop isn't old. I bought it somewhere a year ago, but for the sake of finding solution today i will disasemble and apply new paste to the cpu and gpu, so by the way i will make a photo and show you how it looks like from inside

Take a look at my question here where @DougSmythies helped me with some very useful commands to diagnose etc. Maybe they will help you diagnose too? Unless the only work with Intel processors? Anyway may be of use: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446577/laptop-slow-missing-performance-power-mode-unable-to-change-cpu-governor/1446864#1446864
