Intel i5 M520 fake overheating
My laptop (sony vaio VPCZ13A7E) running ubuntu 22.04 (bad idea, can't downgrade due to the same issue) keeps shutting down due to fake overheating, when i touch the laptop i can feel that it IS NOT HOT AT ALL, in fact sometimes it's cold, when booting it displays that intel ips thermal reporting disabled or something like that, it shutdowns even when i am just at the terminal, doing nothing, looking at the screen, using xfce or even barebones tty isn't helpful at all, can i do something to downclock the cpu or make ubuntu ignore that fake overheating?

I doubt it is Ubuntu that is responsible; the kernel acts on what your BIOS tells it. Might I suggest that if the system is not hot... it might be something else?! check the journal. journalctl -k  to only show kernel message. Or maybe maybe use or add  a | grep shutdown.

I posted a question a while ago which turned out to be due to the CPU PROCHOT flag (which was false in my case) leading to degraded clock speeds. Even if this is not your issue, the person who answered posted some very useful commands to check CPU flags and speeds etc which may help you debug your issue, see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446577

What Ubuntu product & release are you using?  as the 6.1 kernel isn't a standard/supported kernel for any Ubuntu product/release in either GA or HWE stack. It is a kernel used by Debian GNU/Linux & other systems though.

@guiverc i am using ubuntu 22.04, with xfce4 currently

@Rinzwind the command returns nothing, absolute nothing, also it just turned off while running it

Xubuntu 22.04 LTS offered two kernel stacks; with default set by your install media; neither of which was the 6.1 kernel (it was offered by Debian). As 22.04 was a LTS, if you're having trouble with one kernel stack, have you tried switching to another kernel stack option  (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack  where Xubuntu being a flavor still acts like 18.04 with defaults)
